# How to integrate hyperledger explorer into application that interacts with ibm blockchain platform

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I want to integrate hyperledger explorer into my angular application that interacts with my business network which is on the IBM blockchain platform.

My business network is deployed using composer and exposed as a composer REST server which my angular application interacts with.

Does anyone know of any resources to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[integration of IoT in Blockchain](https://www.blogsaays.com/integration-of-iot-hyperledger-fabrics/) is possible if you have the right configuration. I personally checked it using IBM Bluemix. Simple steps to do:
1. Have IoT API ready to connect with Blockchain 
2. Gather those data in synch in every ledger to run successful blockchain application.